# Canon EOS 1100D not turning on

Tags: canon, repair

I am capturing some models today when my Canon 1100D suddenly switched off. I tried all I could, re-inserting the battery and memory card, recharging the battery, re-attach the lens. But all to no avail as the camera refuse to turn on.

Comment: What is your question? The cause of the malfunction? How to fix your camera? How to salvage a session when your camera becomes inoperable? How to properly take care of a paying client when this occurs?

Answer (score 5):

Some options:

1. Try a different battery.
2. Write today off as a loss. It happens.
3. Phone your local camera rental place.
4. Beg or borrow a camera from a friend.

If you're doing this as a business, take the learning experience that this is why you need a backup for every single bit of gear you own.